# Azure Dashboard - You have not configured a web endpoint for monitoring.

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I've a asp.net website deployed to azure. On management portal dashboard I noticed below:

> web endpoint status **PREVIEW**
>
> You have not configured a web endpoint for monitoring.

I also noticed a Monitor tab next to Dashboard which shows monitoring information.

Question:
I'm not understanding, why the above message is shown in Dashboard for web end point status Preview.

Could someone please clarify what is the purpose of the option  and it's differences from monitoring tab.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a new feature introduced recently, whereby you can set up monitoring from different data center locations, to see how well your app is performing. This is only available with Reserved Mode instances.

Here's one site I have, with configuration for  monitoring profiles from both the US and Europe:
[image]

Here's a quick look at some of the data returned:
[image]

You can read more about this feature on ScottGu's blog post [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/03/04/windows-azure-updates-android-support-sql-reporting-services-active-directory-more.aspx).

Comment: Thanks you for explanation, appreciate it.